# Sorting an ArrayList of subclasses using Comparable and compareTo()

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparable, compareto

I have a bank account program that implements a BankAccount superclass which extends to CheckingAccount and SavingsAccount subclasses.

Each account has four properties: first name, last name, social security, and balance.

I have a BankDatabase class that creates a new ArrayList to house each of these objects.

I want to sort this ArrayList using the Comparable interface and compareTo() method.

```
public interface Comparable<BankAccount>
{

    int compareTo(BankAccount other);       
}
```

I've implemented Comparable to my superclass:

```
public abstract class BankAccount implements Comparable<BankAccount>
```

I've written the below compareTo() method:

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(BankAccount other)
    {

        if (this.getBalance() < other.getBalance())
        {
            return -1;
        }

        if (this.getBalance() > other.getBalance())
        {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

I've created a balance getter within the BankAccount superclass.
I've tried using just balance instead of this.getBalance().
Then in my BankDatabase class I am trying to create a void method called print() that will sort the BankAccount objects by balance and print them.

This is where I'm not having trouble. The below code is what I have right now:

```
void print()
    {

        Collections.sort(database);

        for (BankAccount database1 : database)
        {

            System.out.println(database1);

        }

    }
```

For this code, I need to use **Comparable** and **compareTo()** as it is part of an assignment.

I've imported java.util.ArrayList, java.util.Collections, and java.util.List.

Below is my BankDatabase class and the two methods to create a new Checking or Savings account:

```
public class BankDatabase
{

    String first;
    String last;
    List <BankAccount> database;

    BankDatabase()
    {

        database = new ArrayList <BankAccount>();

    }

    void createCheckingAccount(String customerName, String ssn, float deposit)
    {

        String[] customerNames = customerName.split(" ");
        first = customerNames[0];
        last = customerNames[1];

        database.add(new CheckingAccount(first, last, ssn, deposit));

    }

    void createSavingsAccount(String customerName, String ssn, float deposit)
    {

        String[] customerNames = customerName.split(" ");
        first = customerNames[0];
        last = customerNames[1];

        database.add(new SavingsAccount(first, last, ssn, deposit));

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been looking through other threads on here and it seems pretty straightforward using Collections, but it keeps failing.

One of the errors I get is: *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.util.Collections.sort*

Thanks!

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: He does not need to pass a `Comparator` if the element type of his collection is `Comparable` to itself or one of its superclasses, which it is.

Comment: Do provide the stack trace that goes with any exception you receive.  In your particular case, though, the error message itself is quite strange, suggesting perhaps a problem with your IDE.

Comment: What version of Java are you compiling against? What version of Java are you running it with? Are you sure? What **other** *errors* do you get? I notice that both `createSavingsAccount` and `createCheckingAccount` don't set a ***balance*** with the initial ***deposit***; that's probably not right.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, you're right, I was seeing it as a standalone `Comparator`

Comment: Some part of your code didn't compile properly. Usually an IDE issue. Could you try a `Project->Clean...`? Also, probably a dumb question, but I hope you're not re-making the `Comparable` interface. You should be using `java.lang.Comparable`.

Comment: Hi all, appreciate the comments and apologies if my issue and sample code is unclear. @Vineet, that was not a dumb question; I was in fact re-making the Comparable interface. I did not know the standard process that all I had to do was implement. I just deleted the interface that I had created and it now works. I figured it had to be a simple solution. Thanks again everyone.

Comment: You shouldn't have `String first` and `String last` as member variables of the `BankDatabase`. It creates a race condition, and leaves sensitive data available (you can find out the name of the last person to create an account). Instead, just declare them as local variables in the `create*Account` methods.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your interface declaration:

```
public interface Comparable<BankAccount>
{
    int compareTo(BankAccount other);       
}
```

You are defining a new `Comparable` interface - the list elements which you pass to the `Collections.sort` method must implement `java.lang.Comparable`, not just any interface whose simple name is `Comparable`.

The easy fix for this is simply to remove your `Comparable` class.

Alternatively, you could declare that the interface extends the built-in class:

```
public interface Comparable<BankAccount> extends java.lang.Comparable<BankAccount> {
  @Override int compareTo(BankAccount other);
}
```

but there is no particular advantage to this, and it's confusing to have your own interface with the same name as a well-known interface.

---

The other less obvious problem is that the `BankAccount` in your definition doesn't actually refer to the `BankAccount` class you've defined - it's a type variable. It doesn't refer to any type in particular - you could replace it with `T` (i.e. `Comparable<T>`), and it'd do exactly the same.